# Bootstrap List group: Combine two or more list groups with only one active selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

At the moment I am trying to combine Bootstrap [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) and [list group with JS behaviour](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior). Therefore I am getting the set of list groups. Each could have only one active option. Instead of it I would like to have only one active option per accordion.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="accordion col-4" id="accordionVentures">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading1000">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1000" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1000"> 
            Baauw
            </button>
          </div>

          <div id="collapse1000" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1000" data-parent="#accordionVentures">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="list-group"  id="list-tab1000" role="tablist">
                  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id ="list-1000Vlaardingen-list" href="#list-1000Vlaardingen" aria-controls="1000Vlaardingen"  role="tab" data-toggle="list">Vlaardingen</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading2000">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2000"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2000" >
              Blauwhoff
            </button>
          </div>

          <div id="collapse2000" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2000" data-parent="#accordionVentures">
            <div class="card-body">

              <div class="list-group"  id="list-tab2000" role="tablist">
                  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id ="list-2000Aalsmeer-list" href="#list-2000Aalsmeer" aria-controls="2000Aalsmeer" role="tab" data-toggle="list">Aalsmeer</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent1000">
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-1000Vlaardingen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-1000Vlaardingen-list">Vlaardingen</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent2000">
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-2000Aalsmeer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-2000Aalsmeer-list">Aalsmeer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[The jsfiddle link with proper bootstrap interpretation](https://jsfiddle.net/borissokolov/eL814nzg/14/)

UPD: So what I have now is something like:

Step 1. One of the button pressed

[image]

Step 2. Go to another accordion and press one more button

[image]

And I expect to have only one option there:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation was fine. Just that yopu missed `data-toggle="list"` on Aalsmeer button. I have added 2-3 more buttons to make the effect more visible and clear.

You will have to remove `active show` classes from all the `.list-group-item` elements via jquery.

```
$(".list-group-item").on('click', function() {
  $(".list-group-item").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("active show");
  });
})
```

```js
$(".list-group-item").on('click', function() {
  $(".list-group-item").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("active show");
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="accordion col-4" id="accordionVentures">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1000">
      <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1000" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1000"> 
            Baauw
            </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse1000" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1000" data-parent="#accordionVentures">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="list-group" id="list-tab1000" role="tablist">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-1000Vlaardingen-list" href="#list-1000Vlaardingen" aria-controls="1000Vlaardingen" role="tab" data-toggle="list">Vlaardingen</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading2000">
      <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2000" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2000">
        Blauwhoff
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse2000" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2000" data-parent="#accordionVentures">
      <div class="card-body">

        <div class="list-group" id="list-tab2000" role="tablist">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-2000Aalsmeer-list" href="#list-2000Aalsmeer" aria-controls="2000Aalsmeer" role="tab" data-toggle="list">Aalsmeer</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent1000">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-1000Vlaardingen" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-1000Vlaardingen-list">Vlaardingen</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">Messages</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-2000Aalsmeer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-2000Aalsmeer-list">Aalsmeer</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">Settings</div>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent2000">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nandita. I wanted to have one selection for all the groups. So when you have chosen "Messages" and go and press "Settings" - the selection of "Messages" would dissapear

Comment: Putting all the selectable divs in one div will work but it won't remove the active from the element in the other accordian. I think you will have to write a script to remove that active element. Let me try and get back to you

Comment: I have updated the answer, please see if it works for you